# What's the "show implementation" shortcut in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

The key combination I use most in Eclipse is <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd>.
It shows me the implementation of a method. In Android Studio, it shows me the interface, not the implementation.

There doesn't seem to be a "show implementation" shurtcut in Android Studio, or is there?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Its

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> for Go to implementation(s) into Windows and Linux.

Reference :  [Key Commands](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html#KeyCommands) and here is full commands for [Windows/ Linux users](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) and for [Mac users](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf). Search for "Go to implementation(s)"

Comment: I can't see which one of you was first, and I can't accept two answers, sorry.

Comment: This is Ctrl + Alt + Click by default, similar to Ctrl + Click.

Answer (score 18):

- Go to implementation - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- Go to declaration - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `Click`
- Go to type declaration - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- Go to super - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

Some other [shortcuts and tips](http://www.developerphil.com/android-studio-tips-tricks-moving-around/).

Comment: Thanks. Btw, on my keyboard (and I use Ubuntu), it's left ctrl-alt-B, right ctrl-alt-B doesn't work. I'm used to using right ctrl-alt :-)

Comment: @Christine really? Sound strange hahaha, might be some keyboard mapping fault or something like that.

Comment: It's a 1995 Compaq keyboard that I happen to like a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Just in case anyone is having trouble with the shortcuts, you can also do a right click either on the `declaration`, `interface method` or any of the `implementations`

This is an example of my interface method
[image]