# Is there a way to detect and display how many classes implement the Interface in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, interface

My Question is more about the IDE - Android Studio and not related to how to detect the relationship in code.

Suppose I have an interface in my code base  with a name `public interface VehicleInterface`

And this interface is implemented by say, 3 classes in my code base, like

```
Public class Car implements VehicleInterface
Public class Bus implements VehicleInterface
Public class Truck implements VehicleInterface
```

Is there a display/view option in Android Studio IDE which can show me this Interface-Class relationship?

The reason why I am looking for the this option is because our team is working on a legacy code base and we are planning to understand the app system/structure.

One of the starting point we are thinking to understand 1st is these Interface-Class relationship.
Since there are many interfaces all over the code base, we are wondering how many classes might be implementing those....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30075254/9734616 May this will help you.

Comment: thanks @Brijesh. The link gave you has the useful info for me to use it for my need.

Comment: I'll keep that in answer. So any other person can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to implementation - Ctrl + Alt + B
- Go to declaration - Ctrl + B or Ctrl + Click
- Go to type declaration - Ctrl + Shift + B
- Go to super - Ctrl + U

Check all the [key commands](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts).

You can also [create your own keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts#custom) by editing File->Settings->Keymap

Comment: You can also find these options if you right click on the class name and you go to "Go To"